# Need to hide the column in my pdf?

Tags: visualforce, deployment, related-list, rendered

[image]

I have taken a vf page and i that i have to show the related list i have used the below code
in my vf page to show this related list in my pdf.

!

i got but action column is there also i want to hide it in my pdf

Comment: `<apex:page standardController.....>`
means it is a **``visualforce page using standardController``**, not a ``standard page``. And, you can use the way in my previous answer to find the element id or class name and change the css as your wills.

Sorry, I can't give you a detail example at the moment, and since that I delete my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do this by hacking the CSS of your RelatedList by adding a display:none the class name of that column (the css class name is "actionColumn")

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" standardStylesheets="true">
   <style>
    .actionColumn {display:none;}
   </style>
   <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" id="myrelatedlist"/>
</apex:page>
```

But I'm not sure it'll work when you add the renderAs="pdf", if doesn't I think you don't have other choice than doing it manually

Comment: No, its not working..

Comment: @venkatesh, if this is not working, you should not select it as the answer. That would be confusing to people searching the exchange in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Something has simple has this could work:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf">
   <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Opportunity.bucketRate__r}" var="b" title="Bucket Rate Factoring Fee" >
      <apex:column value={!b.levelname__c} />
      <apex:column value={!b.lowdays__c} />
      <apex:column value={!b.highdays__c} />
      <apex:column value={!b.levelfee__c} />
   </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:page>
```

Of course, you might have to adjust your list attribute name and the field names, but this should get you close.

Comment: I never realized you could refer directly to a related list without an extension to bring the extra data in.

Comment: I corrected the code syntax to show how you really reference a related list.  @dphil getting the correct list name is the tricky part.

Comment: Yea, I can figure that out pretty easily.  Hopefully this bit of knowledge that I can actually do this helps me in the future.  I'm sure I could have used this if I had known previously.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are looking for a dirty/quick print, then you are stuck action links. Otherwise you will have to craft the PDF solution more fully.

There are some good resources on the main developer web site - here is one link

[Creating Professional PDF Documents](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce)